# how to dynamically include (or not) relationships

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I'm new to EF5 and LINQ and struggling a bit with the following.

I'm working in an eager load situation, and am wondering how to best write a method to support the following.

entity A has relationships with 3 other entiies.

I want a method returning Listist (no problem)
but I also want the method to have 3 arguments indicating if I want to include each of the 3 other related entities.

so if all three were to be included this works.

```
        var AA = from e in context.A
        .Include( "Bs" )
         .Include( "Cs" )
         .Include( "Ds" )
                    where e.......
                    select e;
```

how can I write it to allow the includes to be either there or not based on my method parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Pass three parameters `bool includeBs`, `bool includeCs` and `bool includeDs` into the method and then use:

```
DbQuery<A> query = context.A;
if (includeBs)
    query = query.Include("Bs");
if (includeCs)
    query = query.Include("Cs");
if (includeDs)
    query = query.Include("Ds");

var AA = from e in query
         where e.......
         select e;
```

As a side note: With EF 5 you should have a strongly typed version of `Include` available which takes a lambda expression instead of a string as parameter, like `Include(a => a.Bs)`. You can use that as well when you replace `DbQuery<A>` above by `IQueryable<A>`.

Comment: Thanks !   I was able to use the Iqueryable,   but used the older style (string) include and it is working.  thanks much